# playn skeletal build excudes jbox2d

Tags: playn, jbox2d

Why does the default playn skeleton project not include jbox2d? And how do I include it in the maven build? I do understand how to include it into my IDE, but I would like the maven build to include this dependency fromt he git go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every game requires it.

For an example using it see:
[sample pom.xml](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/core/pom.xml#16)